# Посчитать кол-во слов в тексте начинающиеся на 'a' и заканчивающиеся на 't' без регулярных выражений, вручную

Tags: java, алгоритм

```java
Scanner text = new Scanner(System.in);
String text2 = text.nextLine();
int kol = 0;
int m = text2.length();

for (int i = 0; i < text2.length(); i++) {
    if ('a' == text2.charAt(i)) {
        if (( (i == 0)||(' ' == text2.charAt(i - 1)))) {
            for(int j = 0;j<text2.length();j++) {
                int t = text2.indexOf(' ', i + 1);
                if (('t' == text2.charAt(t - 1)) || ('t' == text2.charAt(m - 1))) {
                    kol = kol + 1;}}
                }
            } 
        }
    }
}
System.out.print(kol);
```

Работает программа только в некоторых случаях. Вроде алгоритм понятен, но что-то не доходит, например, программа не работает когда нужное слово самое первое (`if (( (i == 0)||(' ' == text2.charAt(i - 1))))`) , хоть и написала( или i == 0).

В общем кучу всяких недочетов. Может есть другой алгоритм?

Comment: конечно напрашивается split по пробелу, но там регулярка на входе...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы делаете цикл с переменной `j`. Он просто не нужен, думаю, объяснять даже не надо, почему. Также, `'t' == text2.charAt(t - 1)` у вас выкинет `IndexOutOfBoundsException` на последнем слове, так как индекс символа пробела будет равным -1.

Исправленный код  будет выглядеть так. Тут изменены некоторые моменты, но в целом он тот же.

```java
String s = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
int count = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    if (s.charAt(i) == 'a') 
        if (i == 0 || s.charAt(i - 1) == ' ') {
            int t = s.indexOf(' ', i + 1);
            if(t == -1)
                t = s.length();
            if (s.charAt(t - 1) == 't')
                count++;
        }

System.out.print(count);
```

Ещё лучше цикл можно записать так. Теперь он будет пропускать символы `a` в середине слов, потому что не увеличивается на единицу (`i++`), а приравнивается к следующему символу `a` после уже найденного конца слова (`i = s.indexOf('a', t + 1)`).

```java
for (int i = s.indexOf('a'), t = 0; i != -1; i = s.indexOf('a', t + 1))
    if(i == 0 || s.charAt(i - 1) == ' ') {
        t = s.indexOf(' ', i + 1);
        if(t == -1)
            t = s.length();
        if(s.charAt(t - 1) == 't')
            count++;
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, очень помогли)

Answer (score 2):

Я бы решал задачу пролистывая слово за словом как то так

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str = scanner.nextLine();

    int ret = 0;
    int ind = 0;

    while (ind < str.length())
    {
        while (ind < str.length() && str.charAt(ind) == ' ') ind++;
        if (ind == str.length()) break;

        int start = ind;
        while (ind < str.length() && str.charAt(ind) != ' ') ind++;
        int end = ind-1;

        if (str.charAt(start) == 'a' && str.charAt(end) == 't') ret++;
    }

    System.out.println(ret);
}
```

Comment: Лучший вариант в своём роде. Сам на практике поступаю точно таким же образом.

Comment: @Sergey Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Конечный автомат с двумя состояниями:
1) Ожидание начала слова. Если обнаружено начало слова, то запоминается, является ли его первая буква буквой 'a'. В любом случае при обнаружении начала слова переходим в состояние ожидания его конца.
2) Ожидание конца слова. Признаком конца слова является пробел (и пр. пробельные символы). При обнаружении конца слова проверяем, что оно начинается с буквы 'a' (мы это запомнили) и последняя извлечённая буква - это буква 't'. Тогда увеличиваем счётчик таких хитрых слов. В любом случае после получения пробела возвращаемся к ожиданию начала следующего слова.

```
enum State {
    EXPECT_START, // ожидание начала слова
    EXPECT_END    // ожидание конца слова
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int counter = 0;
    String text = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
    boolean startWithA = false;
    State state = State.EXPECT_START;
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
        char c = text.charAt(i);
        switch (state) {
            case EXPECT_START:
                if (Character.isSpaceChar(c)) { // ожидали начало, но пришёл конец
                    break;                      // ждем начало дальше
                }
                startWithA = c == 'a';
                state = State.EXPECT_END;
                break;
            case EXPECT_END:
                if (Character.isSpaceChar(c)) { // дождались конца слова
                    if (startWithA) { // если слово начинается на 'a', тогда проверить его последнюю букву
                        char last = text.charAt(i-1);
                        if (last == 't') counter++;
                    }
                    startWithA = false;
                    state = State.EXPECT_START;
                }
                break;
        }
    }
    // анализ конца строки естественным путем выпадает из цикла
    if (startWithA) {
        char last = text.charAt(text.length() - 1);
        if (last == 't') counter++;
    }
    System.out.println(counter);
}
```

Можно придраться конечно же, но практически никаких недочетов.
И алгоритм действительно отличный от других.
Для зачёта сойдёт, если проходили конечные автоматы. Иначе у препода возникнут резонные сомнения: с чего бы такой(ая) шибко умный(ая)?
:)

Comment: Еще пара ответов и мы дойдем до теории компиляторов :)

Comment: Спасибо большое)